# Unable to pass large array to mySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a relatively large HTML form (100+ fields).  I want to take the data from that form and upload it to a mySQL database when the use hits submit.  I have created the PHP code below and have been slowly adding fields and testing to see if the connection is successful.  Everything was working through $skilled_nursing, but when I added the next set of values I am no longer successfully creating database entries.  All of my echo commands are displayed and I am not getting failures in my error log, but the data is not being received in the database.

Can anyone see what is going wrong?  I have checked multiple times for spelling errors, but I haven't seen any.  I am wondering if I am somehow timing out with the connection or if I am trying to stick too many values into the execute command.

```
<?php

echo 'started ok';
// configuration
$dbtype     = "mysql";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "dbname";
$dbuser     = "dbuser";
$dbpass     = "userpass";
echo 'variables assigned ok';
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
echo 'connection established';
// new data
$facility_name = $_POST['facility_name'];
$facility_street = $_POST['facility_street'];
$facility_county = $_POST['facility_county'];
$facility_city = $_POST['facility_city'];
$facility_state = $_POST['facility_state'];
$facility_zipcode = $_POST['facility_zipcode'];
$facility_phone = $_POST['facility_phone'];
$facility_fax = $_POST['facility_fax'];
$facility_licensetype = $_POST['facility_licensetype'];
$facility_licensenumber = $_POST['facility_licensenumber'];
$facility_email = $_POST['facility_email'];
$facility_administrator = $_POST['facility_administrator'];
$skilled_nursing = $_POST['skilled_nursing'];
$independent_living = $_POST['independent_living'];
$assisted_living = $_POST['assisted_living'];
$memory_care = $_POST['memory_care'];
$facility_type_other = $_POST['facility_type_other'];
$care_ratio = $_POST['care_ratio'];
$nurse_ratio = $_POST['nurse_ratio'];



// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO Facilities (facility_name, facility_street, facility_county, facility_city, facility_state, facility_zipcode, facility_phone, facility_fax, facility_licensetype, facility_licensenumber, facility_email, facility_administrator, skilled_nursing, independent_living, assisted_living, memory_care, facility_type_other, care_ratio, nurse_ratio) VALUES (:facility_name, :facility_street, :facility_county, :facility_city, :facility_state, :facility_zipcode, :facility_phone, :facility_fax, :facility_licensetype, :facility_licensenumber, :facility_email, :facility_administrator, :skilled_nursing, :independent_living, :assisted_living, :memory_care, :facility_type_other, :care_ratio, :nurse_ratio)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':facility_state'=>$facility_name,
':facility_street'=>$facility_street,
':facility_county'=>$facility_county,
':facility_city'=>$facility_city,
':facility_state'=>$facility_state,
':facility_name'=>$facility_name,
':facility_zipcode'=>$facility_zipcode,
':facility_phone'=>$facility_phone,
':facility_fax'=>$facility_fax,
':facility_licensetype'=>$facility_licensetype,
':facility_licensenumber'=>$facility_licensenumber,
':facility_email'=>$facility_email,
':facility_administrator'=>$facility_administrator,
':skilled_nursing'=>$skilled_nursing,
':independent_living'=>$independent_living,
':assisted_living'=>$assisted_living,
':memory_care'=>$memory_care,
':facility_type_other'=>$facility_type_other,
':care_ratio'=>$care_ratio,
':nurse_ratio'=>$nurse_ratio));

echo 'query parsed';

?>
```

Comment: Check the contents of $conn->errorInfo(); [http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php][1]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  errorInfo() returns:  'Array ( [0] => 00000 )'  From the article that you posted, I believe that a 0 means a successful connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer what's going wrong with your code, but it might help solve it.

I would do this a bit differently. You say that you have a lot of fields. Your code is likely to get very long and repetitive. Since it looks like your form field names already correspond with your table columns, I would do something more like this (not tested):

```
// get a list of column names that exist in the table
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Facilities'";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
$columns = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

$cols = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    // if a field is passed in that doesn't exist in the table, remove it
    if (!in_array($key, $columns)) {
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}

$cols = array_keys($_POST);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Facilities(". implode(", ", $cols) .") VALUES (:". implode(", :", $cols) .")";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
array_walk($_POST, "addColons");
$q->execute($_POST);

function addColons($value, &$key)
{
    $key = ":{$key}";
}
```

This way, you could have 10, 100, or 1000 fields and this code won't have to change at all. You also reduce your chance for typo errors because there's only one place where the column name is specified. You don't have to worry about SQL injection on the column names because you check to make sure that the column exists before allowing it to be used in your query.

This does, of course, assume that all fields passed in via `$_POST` correspond with column names in your table. If this isn't the case, it may be easiest to just store those particular field values that aren't columns in separate variables and `unset()` them from the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Travesty this is awesome!  It saves me so much repetition and kicks out the mismatched rows.  I added echo $key; below your unset command to help me find typos, but otherwise was able to implement it as is.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Leave that `unset()` column check in there, even after you're done debugging. This prevents SQL injection. Someone else could write a script that will post to your PHP page, so you can't trust that the column names will be the ones you specified in your form.